# Why are cosmic conspiracies considered undesirable in quantum interpretations?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

Quantum interpretations like [superdeterminism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34074/36915%5C), nonlocal hidden variables, etc. are regularly dismissed by the vast majority of physicists because they require "cosmic conspiracies" which can potentially involve anything and everything within the universe, including distant quasars billions of light years away (e.g. from Bell inequality violations), events arbitrarily long ago in the past or far away in the future (e.g. from delayed choice experiments), the "will" of experimenters and their brain states (from complementarity), etc. . This conspiracy has also got to be good enough to escape detection from within. Then, proponents are accused of "paranoia" and as such, not worth debating with any further. Other than premature accusations of "paranoia", are there any good objections against "cosmic conspiracies"?

Let me put it this way. Other than "gut feeling" metaphysical *pre*-judices, what other good objections against cosmic conspiracies are there?

Comment: +1, though that should be "gut feeling" metaphysical HORROR.

Comment: -1 to myself, UNCONSCIOUS metaphysical horror, would be more precise, thanks.

Comment: But that's precisely my point! Unconscious feelings are involved, not rational thinking.

Comment: The basic objection is that such "conspiracies" evolve extremely improbable events. It's like the "theory" that there is no human being behind your posts, instead there was a cat walking randomly on a keyboard which by chance just happened to create meaningful sentences and post them to this site.

Comment: @ Just a 'lil kid: I'm actually a physics obsessed psychologist and it is our collective opinion (LOL)  that the interpretation of quantum mechanics can't be trusted physicists.