# 't Hooft for laypersons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, popular-science, probability, models

I have looked at some of ['t Hooft](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/)'s recent [papers](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub.html) and, unfortunately, they are well beyond my current level of comprehension. The same holds for the discussions that took place on this website. (See, for example, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34217/why-do-people-categorically-dismiss-some-simple-quantum-models).) I therefore tried to imagine what these papers might be about in my own terms. The following is one such imagination.

**Is, possibly, the essence of his recent papers that 't Hooft forces [probability amplitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_amplitude) to be of the form ${\Bbb {Q}}e^{2\pi i{\Bbb Q}}$,* which, I presume, is [dense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) in $\Bbb C$? That is, does 't Hooft provide an unfamiliar, and possibly cumbersome, [interpretation of *probability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_of_probability), which nonetheless might be considered appealing and/or insightful, especially since the set of allowed probability amplitudes is [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) in such an interpretation?**

Is this the gist of his models? Or am I a long way off?

*I'm using ${\Bbb {Q}}e^{2\pi i{\Bbb Q}}$ as a notational shortcut for $\left.\left\{re^{2\pi i \theta}\,\right|\, r,\theta\in\Bbb Q\right\}$.

Comment: Sorry to be mean, but consider $z = (1+i)/\sqrt{2}.$ Then $r = 1$ and $\theta = 1/8$ (in your notation). But clearly $z$ is not of the form $p + q i$ with $p,q \in \Bbb{Q}.$

Comment: @Gugg.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html.  Only a few values of theta would satisfy your condition.

Comment: However, more on-topic, both sets are most definitely dense in $\Bbb{C}.$

Comment: @Vibert and Chris: Thanks! I removed one of the sets from the question. I hope the one that I left is the right one. :)

Comment: The models are deterministic. He constructs a mapping between the evolution of certain wavefunctions in the QFT, and the evolution of grid states in the CA. Probabilities play no part in it.

Comment: @MitchellPorter My primitive and perhaps nonsensical imagination is that he (initially) _resolves_ (perhaps only half of) the dichotomy between probabilistic and deterministic by reinterpreting probabilities to be countable. _Only from there_, he might go from countably infinite to possibly finite (the other half?). Does he skip the initial part? Or is my imagination (completely) off the mark?

Comment: Off the mark. In QM you have states and you have "observables" and the states give the probabilities for the observables. The states (wavefunctions) evolve deterministically, the probabilities only pertain to how they manifest in observables. A state can imply a 100% probability for a particular outcome, then it's an "eigenstate" of that observable...

Comment: 't Hooft considers wavefunctions which, as they evolve, are in an eigenstate, then, after a certain period of time, another eigenstate, and which keep passing through eigenstates at a fixed rate. These "moments when the wavefunction is in an eigenstate" correspond to the discrete timesteps of the cellular automaton.

Comment: @MitchellPorter That is astonishingly clear and informative, filling a big hole in my understanding. (Lots of holes there!) Thank you! Too bad I was way off; I kinda liked where my muddled imagination was going. :)

Comment: @MitchellPorter Would you like to copy-paste your last two comments into an answer?

Comment: @MitchellPorter thanks for that last comment! I always suspected that was what he was doing, but never had time to read the papers in enough depth to figure out if I was right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I'm copy-pasting from @MitchellPorter's comments into this community wiki.)*

**Off the mark.** In QM you have states and you have "observables" and the states give the probabilities for the observables. The states (wavefunctions) evolve deterministically, the probabilities only pertain to how they manifest in observables. A state can imply a 100% probability for a particular outcome, then it's an "eigenstate" of that observable...

**'t Hooft considers wavefunctions which, as they evolve, are in an eigenstate, then, after a certain period of time, another eigenstate, and which keep passing through eigenstates at a fixed rate. These "moments when the wavefunction is in an eigenstate" correspond to the discrete timesteps of the cellular automaton.**