# Is it possible to reproduce the energy spectrum of quantum chaos using classical cellular automata?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, chaos-theory, determinism, cellular-automaton

Is it possible to reproduce the energy spectrum of quantum chaos using classical cellular automata? It's hardly impressive to reproduce harmonic oscillators.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32502/2451

Comment: It is not "hardly impressive" to reproduce harmonic oscillators from classical CA, it is believed by many to be impossible. I don't think it's impossible, but please remember that 'tHooft's claims to have done so are not well accepted yet, and might turn out to be wrong. It is possible to produce any spectrum from a contrived enough 'tHooft model by the way, just by using superpositions of HO's and throwing away all but the lowest energy state (justified by a low-energy limit), which you arrange properly.

Comment: Some say it's trivial, some say it's impossible, some say it's hardly impressive, some say it's wrong wrong wrong. For me, it's as if I hear Moslem extremists argue with Jehovah's witnesses. Isn't is about time that we consider the mathematical equations? The simpler the systems we are discussing, the more transparent things become. What we could try to agree about is that there's nothing mystical about QM. If a "universe" is very small, "ontology" doesn't mean so much anymore, but just consider such systems, and ask yourself what they could become when you replace them by more complex worlds.