# Is the "game of physics" which would use energytesimal (like Planck's quantities) rules to create all physics, time and space etc known?

Tags: spacetime, discrete

Game of Life creates "life" using simple rules. Does something like "game of physics" exist and is it known?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the Planck scale imply that spacetime is discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A new kind of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_New_Kind_of_Science). Not that Wolfram's conclusions are uncontested ([example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4200/)), and that book's contentions for what might be possible should be taken with a gain of salt.

Comment: Wouldn't such rules just be the laws of physics?

Comment: It seems the topic was partially mentioned in many posts, but it seems there is no question about this common planck scale physics vs. cellular automata thing.